# sum of two random variable converges in distribution

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence

It's simple question.

$\{X_n\}, X, Y$ are random variables such that $X_n + cY$ converges to $X+cY$ in distribution for each $c >0$.

How can I show that $X_n$ converges to $X$ in distribution??

I know that $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$ if and only if $P(X_n \leq x) \rightarrow P(X \leq x)$ at every $x$ where $F_X$ is continuous. But cdfs do not seem to help with this problem. I also tried showing that $E[f(X_n)] \to E[f(X)]$ where $f$ is bounded and continuous, but this leads to double limits ($n\to \infty$ and $c\to 0$).

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Actually, I couldn't start to solve problem. I'm completely lost

Comment: @someeed What is the definition of convergence in distribution ? What characterizations of convergence in distribution do you know ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon If $X_n$ converges to $X$ in distribution, $P(X_n \leq x) \rightarrow P(X \leq x)$. This is the definition that I know. I'm not sure what you mean about characterizations of convergence in distribution.

Comment: @someeed This is not the complete definition, you need to specify that $x$ is a point where $F_X$ is continuous. Do you know the characterization with $E(f(X_n))\to E(f(X))$ for every bounded continuous function $f$ ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon Yes. I think I know. That can be proved by Skorohod's theorem. Right?

Comment: @someeed I've edited your original post to add thoughts/context. This isn't much, but it is enough to prevent your question from being closed and later deleted. In the future, always try to provide such writing.

Comment: @GabrielRomon Thanks for you edit. Now I realize my question was not fully provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution via characteristic functions.

For $(t_1,t_2)\in \mathbb R^2$, assuming $t_1\neq 0$,
$$\begin{align}
\phi_{(X_n,Y)}(t_1,t_2) &= E\Big[\exp\big(i(t_1X_n + t_2Y)\big)\Big] \\
&= E\Big[\exp\big(it_1(X_n + \frac{t_2}{t_1}Y)\big)\Big] \\
&= \phi_{X_n + (t_2/t_1) Y}(t_1)\\
&\xrightarrow[n\to \infty ]{} \phi_{X + (t_2/t_1) Y}(t_1)
= \phi_{(X,Y)}(t_1,t_2)
\end{align}$$

and the convergence still holds true when $t_1=0$.

By Levy's theorem, $(X_n,Y)$ converges in distribution to $(X,Y)$ and by the continuous mapping theorem, $X_n\xrightarrow{d}X$.